# Abort failed `dpkg --configure -a`

Tags: apt, software-installation, dpkg

I tried to install a package with `sudo apt-get install [package]`, but most of the way through it froze (due to an incompatibility between the package and my system). I had to hard reboot my system. Now, whenever I try `apt-get install`, `clean`, `remove`, `purge`, etc, I get the error

```
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

The issue is that the configuration is what broke, so `dpkg --configure -a` freezes halfway through and forces me to reboot. Now, I'm stuck in a state I can't seem to get out of. Attempting `dpkg --configure -a` freezes, but any other package-related commands tell me I need to run `dpkg --configure -a`. How can I abort the installation/configuration of this package?

While I'm looking for generic answers, [here's](https://github.com/corbinlc/GNURootDebian/issues/217) the specific issue that causes configure to fail. In case it matters, `dpkg --version` gives `1.17.27 (armhf)`.

Comment: I'm not sure which OS you're running and if journalD is available. But try to  open two shells. In the first run `sudo journalctl -f` this is the system's log. In the second shell run `dpkg --configure -a` - just post the log for further investigation.

Answer (score 16):

Try first by manually cleaning the package:

```
sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/PACKAGE.* /tmp/ 
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq PACKAGE
```

Comment: This worked for removing restoring dpkg!

Comment: An additional tip is to sort the files by time, in 

```/var/lib/dpkg/info/```

it is likely the last file/package that has an issue.